# How do I show that this series converges pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1-\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}$ and I need to show that it converges pointwise for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I'm having a hard time finding a valid comparison. I know that $\dfrac{1-\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\leq \dfrac{x}{n}$, but this isn't usable.

Comment: taylor expansion for cos(x/sqrt(n)) can do the job where (x/sqrt(n)) tends to zero as n tends to infinity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $1 - \cos \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = 2\sin^2 \left(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)\leq 2\cdot \dfrac{x^2}{4n}$.

Thus: $A \leq \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^2}{2n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \text{converges for all $x$ }$

Comment: I was just about to comment the conclusion. I didn't realize this identity. Thank you!

Comment: @user5675443: You are welcome.

Comment: I'm thinking about when this is uniformly convergent, and I think it's when $x\in[a,b]$, a finite closed interval. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{2n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b^2}{2n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. Is this right? Will it not be uniformly convergent for other values of $x$? Also, what can I conclude about the continuity and differentiability of $f$? I know that it's continuous for values where it converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of footwork with Calculus can establish that:
$$\cos(x)\geq 1-\frac{1}2x^2$$
which of course implies
$$1-\cos(x)\leq \frac{1}2 x^2.$$
Using this as an upper bound gives
$$\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\leq \frac{\frac{x^2}n}{2\sqrt{n}}=\frac{x^2}{2n^{3/2}}.$$
Use this for the comparison test.